# Passing JSON to action using REST Console - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

I want to know how to send the parameter 'foo' using the REST Console (chrome pluggin). He should be sent as JSON.

> Blockquote

```
public class ComandaEletronicaWSController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ComandaServlet(Foo foo)
    {
        var action = Request.QueryString["Action"];

        return Json(new { Ok = true });
    }
}
public class Foo
{
    public int bar { get; set; }
    public int beer { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass into the Request Payload.

[image]

Select the content-type as

> application/json

and put your JSON on RAW Body

Comment: And, if you want to pass 2 parameters?? (Imagine foo1 and foo2)

Comment: Request Body can have only one parameter. If you want to pass more than one, you need to encapsulate in some array... [ foo1 : {}, foo2 : {}]